# How to parse array data?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

Im trying to parse following array data by using foreach. But I cannot get it to work. How can I parse from following array data a message and xmlpath information?

Here is the full code to make this question more informative. Im trying to validate XML and XSD schema by using XmlValidator. Goal is to parse the validation information so that I have control over the information the validation produces.

```
$xml = note.xml;
$schema = note.xsd;

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).$ds.'XMLValidator.php');
$validator = new XMLValidator();
$result = $validator->validateXML($xml, $schema);
$result['time'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// Here is the print_r of the $result:
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '<pre/>';   

     Array
    (
        [success] => 
        [messages] => Array
            (
            )

        [errors] => Array
            (
                [0] => LibXMLError Object
                    (
                        [level] => 1
                        [code] => 1549
                        [column] => 0
                        [message] => failed to load external entity "/var/www/html/pdf/notexml"

                        [file] => 
                        [line] => 0
                    )

            )

        [xmlPath] => notexml
        [mainSchemaPath] => notexsd
        [time] => 2015-04-27 23:22:29
    )
```

Comment: What is the expected result of the parsing?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the PHP code you are currently using to attempt this. Even though it is not working, it will give people something to start with to help you understand why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into PHP foreach function. You can do something like this:

```
foreach($array as $arr){
  $xmlpath = $arr['xmlPath'];
}
```

Comment: foreach($result as $arr){
  echo $xmlpath = $arr['xmlPath'];
} 

Tried that but for some reason echo gives me value of: nn2  

When Im expecting value of: notexml